# TFS 2013 Syncronizing branch with parent

Tags: c#, tfs, branching-and-merging

This question may have been answered already, but I could not find a suitable answer.

I am using TFS 2013 and we have started to devlop using a branch per function type of methodology.

This is working fine, but I came across an issue with the branch I am currently working on.

The system is a web based application that uses WCF interfaces to talk to the database and provide business logic.

A co-worker updated one of the interfaces and then went on to change some of the web application.

These changes have now but checked back in and merged back into the main developement branch.

On looking at my branch, it now breaks because of the changes to the WCF interface.

My question is, is it possible to promote the checked in changes that my co-worker made to my branch so that it fixes the issues I now have?

If so, how is it done?

Or do I have to re-branch form the main devlopment branch again?

Thanks

Comment: [Looks like I found the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317703/tfs-updating-branch-with-changes-from-main?rq=1) Thanks to all that looked

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your branch from Main Development Branch, there is no reason why you can't run a "merge" from Main Development to your branch to get the updates. I suggest you check in all your Pending Changes on your branch  and run "Get Latest" on both branches first before doing the "merge" otherwise you can end up with issues during the merge (it becomes very messy working out conflicting differences between 3 different versions).

It's a fairly common use-case when running with a multiple branching strategy to update the branch you're working on if the Main (trunk) branch is updated.

Comment: So, currently we have a Main trunk from which two branches are created. The first branch is checked in and merged back into the main trunk. Now I wish to effectively do a get latest to update the changed now in the main branch into branch 2. When I do a Get Latest, all that does is check to see for changed that are outstanding locally, NOT between the branches

Comment: He means do a Get Latest on both branches first and make sure everything is checked in or shelved which will make the merge easier. Then merge from Main to Branch 2. This will get the changes from Branch 1 to 2 via Main